# SharePoint Online 2013 Hide search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

We have the following requirement.
In SharePoint search, we need to restrict the users from seeing items that were not created by them. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Can I achieve this using Audience Targeting? Does targeting a content to specific people hides the content from rest of the people while searching?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the created by field and filter on that.

As explained in detail here:

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/filtering-content-with-sharepoint-user-properties-search

**Note:** Normally I would not post answer's like this, but can't re-make the guide at work (blocks the images).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a result source in SharePoint and use KQL to not show items in the result source if they were not created by the user who is viewing the results.

Adding this logic to a search query will only show content that was created by the user initiating the query:

```
CreatedBy:{User.Name}
```